# destrying session not working

Tags: php, jquery, session

I am creating a session for a login logout system. But my session_destroy isn't working. The session variable is still there once I click logout.

Here's how I create my session.

```
session_start();
$username = $_GET['username'];
$_SESSION["username"] = $username;
header('Location: employeepage.php');
```

Then here's how I recieve it.

```
session_destroy();
header('Location: login.php');
```

When I click logout using jquery. I redirect to a page where the session should be destroyed.

```
$('#logoutbtn').live("click",function(){
    window.location.replace("logout.php");
});
```

And here is how I destroy it.

```
session_destroy();
header('Location: login.php');
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also neee to call `session_start()` before using `session_destroy`.

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php):

```
session_start();

// Unset all of the session variables.
$_SESSION = array();

// If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
// Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

// Finally, destroy the session.
session_destroy();
```

Comment: Wow. That did the trick! Thanks! Will accept tour answer in 8 minutes.